# Regular Expression to not to match period (.) from text(only alpha) but from alphanumeric text

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, regexp-replace

```
SELECT regexp_replace('FRAME  WINDOW MASTER. 160.055-44.9 ADULT Z68.41', '[^A-Z0-9%+/.+ '']', ' ') 
FROM DUAL;
```

The result i get is

```
FRAME  WINDOW MASTER. 160.055 44.9 ADULT
```

but i want the Result to be

`FRAME  WINDOW MASTER 160.055 44.9 ADULT`  ( master without period)

Comment: What's the rule here ?

Comment: MASTER. or TEX.T ( where there are no numbers in the word)should be replaced with space but 160.055-44.9 or Z68.41 shouldn't be.

Comment: Space or nothing ?

Comment: Space is fine, i will change it according to the need once i get the feature working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this do the trick?

```
"[^A-Z0-9%+/.+ '']|\.\s"
```

I'm not sure exactly what you want but it gives the output you want.

Edit this is the fix:

```
[^A-Z0-9%+/.+ '']|\.(\s|$)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, It removes the period  from the MASTER but not from the TEMPORA
SELECT regexp_replace('FRAME DD.XX WINDOW MASTER. 160.055-44.9 ADULT Z68.41 TEMPORA.', '[^A-Z0-9%+/.+ '']|\.\s', ' ') FROM DUAL;

Comment: It has to remove period from words which contain text but not from alphanumeric.

Comment: The problem is with the last word if as it is not having space.

Comment: @user2284342 I uploaded a fix.

Comment: @user2284342 np ^^ could you select this as the answer then?

Answer (score 0):

You can match for `.` after a character and replace groups like this.

**Regex:** `(\D)\.` and replace with `\1[space]`

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xJ0lT1/6)**

---

You can match for `.` between two characters and replace groups like this.

**Regex:** `(\D)\.(\D)` and replace with `\1[space]\2`

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xJ0lT1/8)**

---

You could also use `look around` assertions like this. **Skeptical about it's support in Oracle.**

**Regex:** `(?<=\D)\.(?=\D)` and replace with `[space]`

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xJ0lT1/7)**